# I'm missing a specific property value in CSS on deployment. Why?

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment, netlify

A section of my app uses triangle overlays on videos. In deployment, the border width values of those triangles change from a development environment.

I have narrowed down the problem to the following.

Localhost

```
    border-width: 250px 100vw 0 0;
```

Deployed via Netlify/Github

```
    border-width: 250px 0 0;
```

How come the border-right shorthand value '100vw' went away?

My first attempt at fixing this included deleting the app then redeploying it.

I have also tried not using the short hand for border-width:

```
border-top-width: 250px;
border-right-width: 100vw;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
```

This is my triangle (my apologies this is in SCSS)

```
 .triangle-grey-white {
    border-width: 250px 100vw 0 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    border-right-color: transparent !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    border-top-color: color(backgroundcolor);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

and when I deploy here: https://focused-pare-64d9aa.netlify.com/

This is what it changes to

```
.triangle-grey-white {
      border-width: 250px 0 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-bottom-color: transparent!important;
      border-right-color: transparent!important;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 4;
      border-top: 250px #fff;
      border-style: solid;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

I have no idea why it changes.

Comment: You should process the site locally with the same build command as Netlify, then inspect the css in your deploy folder to make sure it is processing the way you are saying. Also make sure you have pushed all those changes to your repository. Other than that it will be hard to give you an answer without seeing how the project is setup.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue occurs in the production version of the app. I deployed the development version and it worked perfectly so it may be a webpack issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Netlify or Github has anything to do with this, it seems it's your project configuration, I would build it locally first and check that is being built correctly.